# Blank images in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image

Hex there, we're getting blank/white images randomly on our featured images in WP. We upgraded to cloud hosting, but it didn't fix the issue. Hosting says the issue is on my end. What should I do? I tried to disable all plugins, and it didn't fix it.

Any suggestions? That would help a lot.

Comment: Typically on this site it's best to provide some code snippets to show what's happening. And also best to outline things you've already tried to do to fix the issue. In this instance, I'd suggest editing your question, and add the code from your theme that outputs the featured image, so we can have a look at that to see if there's something wrong in there.

Comment: You can flush permalink from settings -> permalinks and click to save changes. After Permalink flush you visit your website and check the search console error. If you can't solve the problem you can share your current theme file with wetransfer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.